# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in H:\wamp\www\main\index.php on line 366

Tags: php, jquery, parsing, error-handling

```
    if ($page > 0) {

        echo "<span class=\"paginate\"> <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?search=$search&orderby=$orderby'>&nbsp; <b>&lt;&lt;</b> FIRST &nbsp;</a></span> ";

    } else {
        echo "<span class=\"disabled\">&nbsp; <b>&lt;&lt;</b> FIRST &nbsp;</span> ";
    } 
    if ($page > 1) {
        $previous = $page-1;

        echo "<span class=\"paginate\"> <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?search=$search&page=$previous&orderby=$orderby'>&nbsp; <b>&lt;</b> PREVIOUS &nbsp;</a></span> ";
    } else {
        echo "<span class=\"paginate\">&nbsp; <b>&lt;</b> PREVIOUS &nbsp;</span> ";
    }

    if ($page == $lastx) {

        $lastx = $page;


        echo " <span class=\"paginate\"> &nbsp; NEXT <b>&gt;</b> &nbsp;</span>";
        echo " <span class=\"paginate\"> &nbsp; LAST <b>&gt;&gt;</b> &nbsp;</span> ";

    } else {

        $next = $page+1;
        echo " <span class=\"paginate\"> <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?search=$search&page=$next&orderby=$orderby'>&nbsp; NEXT <b>&gt;</b> &nbsp;</a></span>";
        echo " <span class=\"paginate\"> <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?search=$search&page=$lastx&orderby=$orderby'>&nbsp; LAST <b>&gt;&gt;</b> &nbsp;</a></span> ";
    }
    echo "</div><br><br>";


    } else  { 
        echo "<center><div class=\"error\" >nothing found for <b>". $_GET['search']." </b>\n</div></center>"; }
    }                            // **(this line as 366)**
  else { ?>
<div align="center" style="margin-top:30px;">


    <div id="srcbox">
        <form action="<?=$CFG['domain']?>/index.php" method="get" onsubmit="this.submit();return false;">
            <input class="src" name="search" type="text" autocomplete="off" delay="1500" value="type and go..." onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='type and go...';" onFocus="if(this.value=='type and go...') this.value='';">

            <input type="image" src="<?=$CFG['domain']?>/img/submit.png" name="Submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>




find this word "(this line as 366)"
```

Comment: } else  { echo "<center><div class=\"error\" >nothing found for <b>". $_GET['search']." </b>\n</div></center>"; }
}  (this line as error line 366)
  else

Comment: there is not any if part available related to this else part

Comment: remove this code 
    } else  { echo "<center><div class=\"error\" >nothing found for <b>". $_GET['search']." </b>\n</div></center>"; }
}                            // **(this line as 366)**
  else
{ ?>

Answer (score 1):

You closed it twice where you said

> // **(this line as 366)**

and need a

> }

After the

```
<div id="srcbox">
```

and the final code:

```
 if ($page > 0) {

echo "<span class=\"paginate\"> <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?search=$search&orderby=$orderby'>&nbsp; <b>&lt;&lt;</b> FIRST &nbsp;</a></span> ";
}else {
    echo "<span class=\"disabled\">&nbsp; <b>&lt;&lt;</b> FIRST &nbsp;</span> ";
}

    if ($page > 1) {
$previous = $page-1;

echo "<span class=\"paginate\"> <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?search=$search&page=$previous&orderby=$orderby'>&nbsp; <b>&lt;</b> PREVIOUS &nbsp;</a></span> ";
}else {
    echo "<span class=\"paginate\">&nbsp; <b>&lt;</b> PREVIOUS &nbsp;</span> ";
    }

    if ($page == $lastx) {

$lastx = $page;


echo " <span class=\"paginate\"> &nbsp; NEXT <b>&gt;</b> &nbsp;</span>";
    echo " <span class=\"paginate\"> &nbsp; LAST <b>&gt;&gt;</b> &nbsp;</span> ";
} else {

        $next = $page+1;
        echo " <span class=\"paginate\"> <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?search=$search&page=$next&orderby=$orderby'>&nbsp; NEXT <b>&gt;</b> &nbsp;</a></span>";
        echo " <span class=\"paginate\"> <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?search=$search&page=$lastx&orderby=$orderby'>&nbsp; LAST <b>&gt;&gt;</b> &nbsp;</a></span> ";
        }
echo "</div><br><br>";


    } else  { echo "<center><div class=\"error\" >nothing found for <b>". $_GET['search']." </b>\n</div></center>"; }
  else
{ ?>
<div align="center" style="margin-top:30px;">


    <div id="srcbox">
        <form action="<?=$CFG['domain']?>/index.php" method="get" onsubmit="this.submit();return false;">
            <input class="src" name="search" type="text" autocomplete="off" delay="1500" value="type and go..." onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='type and go...';" onFocus="if(this.value=='type and go...') this.value='';">

            <input type="image" src="<?=$CFG['domain']?>/img/submit.png" name="Submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```